# How to check conformal invariance of a Lagrangian?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, symmetry, field-theory, conformal-field-theory, majorana-fermions

The Lagrangian is

$$\mathcal{L}=\frac{-\dot\iota}{2}\Big(\Phi^\dagger\frac{\partial\Phi}{\partial x^0}+\Phi\frac{\partial\Phi^\dagger}{\partial x^0}+\Phi^\dagger\frac{\partial\Phi^\dagger}{\partial x^1}-\Phi\frac{\partial\Phi}{\partial x^1}\Big)$$

The above Lagrangian is for Majorana fermions.

Comment: What have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The action in two-dimensional Minkowski space is 
$$S=\int dx^0dx^1(-\dot\iota)\bar\Psi\Gamma^\mu\partial_\mu\Psi$$
where $$\Psi=\begin{pmatrix}\Phi\\ \Phi^\dagger\end{pmatrix}$$
We can perform Wick's rotation $x^0\mapsto\dot\iota x^0$ under which partial derivative transforms as $\partial_1\to\dot\iota\partial_1$. This is same as choosing $\Gamma$-matrices
$$\Gamma^1=\begin{pmatrix}0&-\dot\iota\\ \dot\iota&0\end{pmatrix}$$
and additional $\dot\iota$ factor in integration above. We can write
\begin{align}\Gamma^0\Gamma^\mu\partial_\mu&=\Gamma^0(\Gamma^0\partial_0+\Gamma^1\partial_1)\\
&=\begin{pmatrix}\partial_0+\dot\iota\partial_1&0\\ 0&\partial_0-\dot\iota\partial_1\end{pmatrix}\\
&=2\begin{pmatrix}\partial_{\bar z}&0\\ 0&\partial_z\end{pmatrix}\end{align}
The action after calculating Jacobian of transformation is
\begin{align}S&=\int dzd\bar z\bar\Psi\begin{pmatrix}\partial_{\bar z}&0\\ 0&\partial_z\end{pmatrix}\Psi\\
&=\int dzd\bar z(\Phi\bar\partial\Phi+\bar\Phi\partial\bar\Phi)\end{align}
First thing is to realize that $\Phi$ is chiral field, to do so we derive equation of motion by varying the action with respect to the fields $\Phi$ and $\Phi^\dagger$
\begin{align}0=\delta_\Phi S&=\int d^2z\big(\delta\Phi\bar\partial\Phi+\Phi\bar\partial(\delta\Phi)\big)\\
&=\int d^2z\big(\delta\Phi\bar\partial\Phi+\bar\partial(\Phi\delta\Phi)-(\bar\partial\Phi)\delta\Phi\big)\\
&=2\int d^2z\delta\Phi\bar\partial\Phi\end{align}
Since the equation has to be true for all variations $\delta\Phi$, we find equation of motion
$$\bar\partial\Phi=0$$
Similarly, by variying field $\delta\Phi^\dagger$, we find
$$\partial\Phi^\dagger=0$$
which means $\Phi=\Phi(z)$ is primary field and  $\Phi^\dagger=\Phi^\dagger(\bar z)$ is anti-chiral field. Next we will see that action is invarient under conformal transformation if the field $\Phi$ and $\Phi$ are primary field with conformal dimensions $(h,\bar h)=(\frac{1}{2},0)$, and $(h,\bar h)=(0,\frac{1}{2})$ respectively.
\begin{align}S\to &\int dzd\bar z\Big(\Phi'(z,\bar z)\partial_{\bar z}\Phi'(z,\bar z)+\bar\Phi'(z,\bar z)\partial_{z}\bar\Phi'(z,\bar z)\Big)\\
=&\int\frac{\partial z}{\partial w}dw\frac{\partial\bar z}{\partial\bar w}d\bar w\Big(\big(\frac{\partial w}{\partial z}\big)^{\frac{1}{2}}\Phi(w,\bar w)\frac{\partial \bar w}{\partial \bar z}\partial_{\bar w}\big(\frac{\partial w}{\partial z}\big)^{\frac{1}{2}}\Phi(w,\bar w)\\
&+\big(\frac{\partial\bar w}{\partial\bar z}\big)^{\frac{1}{2}}\bar\Phi(w,\bar w)\frac{\partial w}{\partial z}\partial_{w}\big(\frac{\partial\bar w}{\partial\bar z}\big)^{\frac{1}{2}}\bar\Phi(w,\bar w)\Big)\\
=&\int dwd\bar w \Big(\Phi(w,\bar w)\partial_{\bar w}\Phi(w,\bar w)+\bar\Phi(w,\bar w)\partial_{w}\bar\Phi(w,\bar w)\Big)\end{align}

This shows that action is indeed invarient under conformal transformation if $\Phi$ and $\Phi^\dagger$ are primary field of dimension $\frac{1}{2}$.

**Doubt which still pertains**: We showed the action is invarient under conformal transformation if $\Phi$ and $\Phi^\dagger$ are primary field of dimension $\frac{1}{2}$. But, how do we know that the conformal dimension are $\frac{1}{2}$?

(Source: Introduction to Conformal Field Theory by R Blumenhagen and  E Plauschinn)