# Finding conformal dimension from given Lagrangian

Tags: conformal-field-theory

How can I find conformal dimension $(h,\bar{h})$ of field $\Phi$, if Lagrangian density is

$$\mathcal{L}=\frac{-\dot\iota}{2}\Big(\Phi^\dagger\frac{\partial\Phi}{\partial x^0}+\Phi\frac{\partial\Phi^\dagger}{\partial x^0}+\Phi^\dagger\frac{\partial\Phi^\dagger}{\partial x^1}-\Phi\frac{\partial\Phi}{\partial x^1}\Big)$$

This Lagrangian density is associated with Majorana fermions. Originally, I wanted to find out the two-point correlation.

Comment: Related post by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/538770/2451

Comment: It's a free theory, you could compute the energy-momentum tensor $T$, and then use the known form of the OPE between $T$ and $\Phi$.